# Processing maildir files

Tags: email, maildir

I've used the excellent getmail utility to download several thousand emails from an IMAP account to my local machine. I now have the email in maildir format and need a way of parsing them. I'd like to rename these files in a specific format, which is the concatenation of the timestamp, subject, and sender. Can anybody recommend a tool or API for parsing maildir files to enable me to do so? I'd like to be able to use PHP as the next step in this project involves using a library written in PHP, but I'm flexible in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The [Plancake email parser](https://github.com/plancake/official-library-php-email-parser/blob/master/PlancakeEmailParser.php), which I modified slightly to better suit my needs, really helped make quick work of parsing the email messages.